# Jquery - change image on mouseover

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery and was looking into some nice effect of changing pictures on mouseover.
I'm totally new, so I don't want to ask for a full code of solution (if someone does want to help with that, I would not mind as I'm learning)

My goal: https://ibb.co/gMwM5k

Description: So, for instance I've two pictures - A and B. I want to be able to display picture A and on mouseover (base on only y coordinate - moving left/right) 
change it to picture B, but as showed in picture (so that A image still stays, but just the one part).

Maybe someone could give me useful articles on what I need, to make this happen. Also small pseudo-code would be awesome on the correct way of structuring this!

Also, is this a hard job for newcomer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var mouseX = 0,
  second = $(".second"),
  xp = 0,
  offset = 10,
  clrTimeout = null,
  limitX = $('.container').width() - offset;
$('.container').mousemove(function(e) {
  clearTimeout(clrTimeout);
  mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, limitX);
  if (mouseX < offset) mouseX = offset;
  xp += (mouseX - xp);
  second.css({
    left: xp
  });
});
```

```css
img,
.container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

.first,
.second {
  position: absolute
}

.second {
  left: 40%
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&bg=ff44ff&w=200&h=200" alt="Image1" /></div>
  <div class="second"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&bg=33ff44&w=200&h=200" alt="Image1" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This page might be useful to you:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-create-jquery-slide-left-and-right-toggle-effect.php

you can use the slide example shown here and target and img that is overtop another img

you can place the images on top of each other using css. checkout the "position: absolute;" style.